# VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for both all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED)

Tags: virtualbox, xamarin-studio

Downloaded Xamarin Android Player and with >>next>> progress installed Virtual Box.

When I tried to start an emulator I got

```
Failed to initialized device (name Of the emulator)
VboxManager Commendt Failed
```

and the detail of the error in Oracle Vm Virtualbox is

```
VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for both all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED)
```

How can I fix this?

**I have found the solution of my problem, put some images to help others, thanks**
[go here](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/54479/vt-x-is-disabled-in-the-bios-for-both-all-cpu-modes-verr-vmx-msr-all-vmx-disabled#latest)

Comment: This is more of a superuser.com question, but try this : http://www.sysprobs.com/disable-enable-virtualization-technology-bios

Comment: If you've solved your problem, you should add an answer here instead of linking to an outside Web site.

Comment: I have found the solution of my problem, put some images to help others, thanks go here --> 
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/54479/vt-x-is-disabled-in-the-bios-for-both-all-cpu-modes-verr-vmx-msr-all-vmx-disabled#latest

Answer (score 217):

It is a RAM related issue. The documentation is self explanatory:

> You are trying to allocate >3GB of RAM to the VM. This requires: (a) a
>   64 bit host system; and (b) true hardware pass-through ie VT-x.

**Fast solution**

Allocate less than 3GB for the virtual machine.

**Complete solution**

1. Make sure your system is 64 bit.
2. Enable virtualisation in your host machine. You can find how to do it [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/213795/how-to-enable-intel-vt-x-in-your-computers-bios-or-uefi-firmware/) or there are many other resources available on [Google](https://www.google.es/#safe=off&q=Enable+virtualization+in+your+computer).

Comment: Fast solution didn't work on my system. Had to enable virtualization in bios. (Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: It _can_ be a RAM issue. But that's only one possibility.

Answer (score 162):

Turning PAE/NX on/off didn't work for me. I just needed to turn on virtualization on my computer. I was working on a HP Compaq 8200 and followed the steps below to turn on virtualization. If you are working on a different computer, you probably just need to look up how to turn on virtualization on your pc. The steps below for HP Compaq 8200 (or similar) is copied verbatim from the comment posted by the user qqdmax5 on Hp discussion board [here](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Desktop-Operating-Systems-and-Recovery/Cann-t-enable-the-virtualization-technology-on-the-BIOS/td-p/1117669).

---

To run Oracle VM Virtual Box / VMware machines on 64-bit host there is a need to enable Virtualization Technology (VTx) and Virtualization Technology Directed I/O (VTd).

Usually these setting are disabled on the level of BIOS.

To enable VTx and VTd you have to change corresponding settings in the BIOS.

Here is an example how to do it for HP Compaq 8200 or similar PC:

1. Start the machine.
2. Press F10 to enter BIOS.
3. Security-> System Security
4. Enable Virtualization Technology (VTx) and Virtualization Technology Directed I/O (VTd).
5. Save and restart the machine.

---

There is also some discussion on this on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/256853).

Comment: +1 Thanks for this answer. For my Lenovo PC I had to do http://amiduos.com/support/knowledge-base/article/enabling-virtualization-in-lenovo-systems

Comment: After a Window update my BIOS settings had changed. To get it working again I had to disable Vt-d and enable hardware virtualisation in the BIOS.

Comment: This is the right answer for all the users whose bios settings (VTx) has been disabled. Thanks for posting.

Comment: In my BIOS I had to enable "Intel Virtualization Technology".

Comment: This was also the issue for me, running an older HP EliteBook laptop and Linux OS. F10 > BIOS > System Config. > VirtualizationTechnology

Comment: "restart the machine" is important: on my thinkpad I had to powercycle to have Vtx enabled

Comment: +1 works for me... I have shutdown my machine. On restart press F10/Esc... then changed the setting and restarted again.

Comment: This worked for me.  I should note that on my Windows 10 PC the option on step 4 was just "Enable Virtualization Technology (VTx)" That was disabled by default.

Comment: I have to update my BIOS (Lenovo W550s) in other to use VM

Answer (score 62):

In Virtual Box "Settings" > System Settings > Processor > Enable the PAE/NX option. It resolved my issue.

Comment: I had to uncheck Enable PAE/NX.  This made the error go away and the virtual machine started!

Comment: How does this differ from http://stackoverflow.com/a/34741964/1221410 ?  Which was listed around 3 years prior to this answer?

Comment: Didn't work for me too. However in Settings > System > Acceleration, I unchecked "Enable VT-x/AMD-V" and then it works! (I disabled back the PAE/NX option).

Comment: Temporary solution. If you are working with Vagrant or other technology, then it will not work. (At least not worked for me. :( )

Answer (score 17):

I had this issue when tried to run a 32-bit OS with more than 3584 MB of RAM allocated for it. Setting the guest OS RAM to 3584 MB and less helped.

But i ended just enabling the flag in BIOS nevertheless.

Answer (score 15):

Follow the steps below in Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager:

1. Select the Virtual device and choose **Settings**
2. Navigate to **System** and click the **Processor** tab
3. Tick the check-box, **Enable PAE/NX**
4. Click **OK** and you are done

To verify, start the Virtual device from Oracle VM VirtualBox. If all has gone well, the device boots up.

Close this device and open it from Genymotion.

Answer (score 9):

For latest Windows 10 (HP & Intel motherboard/processor),

Follow the below steps, starting with :

```
Settings ->
Update & Security ->
Recovery ->
Advanced startUp -> Restart now

F10 (System Recovery) -> System Configuration tab -> Virtualization Technology
```

Enable

F10 to save and exit

Comment: Thanks. This gets all Windows users going in the right direction.  I have an ASUS motherboard and had to shut down from the Advanced Startup menu and then physically start to see a BIOS option (F2/Del for ASUS)... once in BIOS it was under Advanced => Advanded Configuration => CPU and called Intel Virtualization Technology.

Answer (score 9):

For Ubuntu on HP (Intel processors),

**Press F10** on booting the system, it will enter into system setup mode.

You will find tabs on top like Main, Security, Advanced.

Go into **Advanced >>** and click on **System** settings.

Mark the check boxes on Enable Virtualization Technology (VTx) and Virtualization Technology Directed I/O (VTd).

Back to Main, click on save changes and exit.

Answer (score 8):

enable PAE/NX in virtualbox network config

Answer (score 6):

My BIOS VT-X was on, but I had to turn PAE/NX off to get the VM to run.

Answer (score 6):

**You need to enable virtualization using BIOS setup.**

step 1. Restart your PC and when your PC booting up then press your BIOS setup key (F1 or F2 or google it your BIOS setup key).

step 2. Go to the security menu.

step 3. Select virtualization and enable it.

Note:- BIOS setup depends on PC Manufacturer-brand.

Comment: This worked on ASUS motherboard's BIOS by enabling Intel Virtualization Technology option!

Answer (score 5):

If you're on 32-bit machine don't allow more than 3584 MB of RAM and it will run.

Answer (score 4):

I had to turn PAE/NX off and then back to on...voila !!

Comment: I agree, the same worked for me. Windows 10 x64, Virtual Box 5.0.14. I had to disable PAE/NX in VB options and it helped.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure Virtualization is enabled in your bios.

Answer (score 2):

Simply check how many CPUs you are allocating. With one CPU you do not need to play with your bios.

Comment: Had a similar thing, and the other above solutions didn't work.  My imported VM had 4 CPU's set, reduced it to just the one (`vboxmanage VMNAME --cpus 1`) and booted like a charm.  Thanks Denis.

Answer (score 2):

Open your BIOS and enable virtualization.