# Error Failed To Initialize

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-android-player

I have been trying to use the xamarin android player for while now but I just get this error saying "failed to initialize device nexus 4(lolipop) VBoxManage command failed. see log for further details"I have uninstalled the player and xamerin numerous time but still this issue persists I have checked the log file although I am not sure what I am looking for to fix this.I have installed it on someone elses machine and it work first time. Here is the end of the log file maybe it will help someone help me figure this out thanks for ny help on the issue.Here is a link to an image of the error https://i.stack.imgur.com/iX5ww.jpg.

```
00:00:01.767607 ********************* End of CFGM dump **********************
00:00:01.767619 VM: fHMEnabled=true (configured) fRecompileUser=false fRecompileSupervisor=false
00:00:01.767621 VM: fRawRing1Enabled=false CSAM=true PATM=true 
00:00:01.767778 VMSetError: F:\tinderbox\win-5.0\src\VBox\VMM\VMMR3\HM.cpp(576) int __cdecl HMR3Init(struct VM *); rc=VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED
00:00:01.767802 VMSetError: VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for both all CPU modes
00:00:01.894133 ERROR [COM]: aRC=E_FAIL (0x80004005) aIID={872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed} aComponent={ConsoleWrap} aText={VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for both all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED)}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:00:01.894502 Console: Machine state changed to 'PoweredOff'
00:00:01.905868 Power up failed (vrc=VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED, rc=E_FAIL (0X80004005))
```

Comment: Could be a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33304393/vt-x-is-disabled-in-the-bios-for-both-all-cpu-modes-verr-vmx-msr-all-vmx-disabl/33992223

Comment: Do you have VT-x enabled in the BIOS and what version of Virtual box is installed?

Comment: hi i went into the bios and in system configuration it said visualization technology is  disabled i think that is the vt-x am i right? also the virtual box version is version 5.0.10 r104061, sorry i haven't gotten back to you in awhile didnt know someone responded other information its a windows 8.1 machine, thanks for any help you can give me with this issue

Comment: enabled virtual technology in the bios its working now thanks

Answer (score -2):

The solution was to enabled virtual technology in the bios.

It's working now thanks everyone