# failed to open a session for the virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtualization

i have this problem when opening a virtual machine in virtual box:

```
    Not in a hypervisor partition (HVP=0) (VERR_NEM_NOT_AVAILABLE).
VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED).


Result Code: 
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: 
ConsoleWrap
Interface: 
IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

i searched for a solution and i found that i must enable the virtualization from the the BIOS setup but when i checked it i found it enabled. can anyone provide me a solution?

Comment: you'll have to enable CPU Virtualization on the system BIOS

Comment: You could check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33304393/vt-x-is-disabled-in-the-bios-for-both-all-cpu-modes-verr-vmx-msr-all-vmx-disabl he seems to have the same problem as you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start your PC, press `F2` or `F12` or `DEL`, go to the security option and enable `VT technology`.
In some new BIOS, it called Virtual technology or Intel virtualization in the CPU setting option

Comment: I use Asus Zendbook 14. I was enable Intel VT in BIOS but Genymotion doesn't start up phone emulator